# Replace with a regex formula prop has quotation mark issue

Tags: javascript, regex, replace, prop, notion-api

On notion i am trying to create a formula. that uses replace inside of a replaceall with a regex im having an issue on putting the prop value inside the double quotes in the replace.

The code in working state;

```
replaceAll(replace(prop("all chapter numbers"), "(?:[^,]*,){2}", ""), ",.*", "");
```

What i am trying to accomplish to

```
replaceAll(replace(prop("all chapter numbers"), "/(?:[^,]*,){prop("total checked chapter")}", ""), ",.*", "")
```

I have tried to use the template literal instead of the simple quotation.
Which resulted on notion formula not recognizing the code and simply telling me " needed.

Because i had no clue about JavaScript and template literal i have did some research and try to replicate from the examples.

Firstly because notion reaplace formula looking much diffrent that what i have seen on javascript sites i tried to do it on one replace then add the other one afterwards.

[notion replace](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zgs4X.png)

```
replace("Visit Microsoft","Microsoft","W3Schools");
```

[notion replaceAll](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SyZxY.png)

javascript examples i have seen

```
let text = "Visit Microsoft!";
let result = text.replace("Microsoft", "W3Schools");
```

implementing onto my issue

Try1:

```
replace(prop("all chapter numbers")),`(?:[^,]*,)${prop("total checked chapter")}`, ``)
```

Output syntax error

[try1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/494035/how-do-you-use-a-variable-in-a-regular-expression)

```
replace(prop("all chapter numbers"),`(?:[^,]*,){${total checked chapter}}`,"" )
```

[try1.1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wLAqt.png)

I have checked [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/494035/how-do-you-use-a-variable-in-a-regular-expression)

That i have to use new regExp but i got no info on the web how to use a newregex on the syntax of notion replace formula.

from the [w3 school](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_string_templates.asp) example i tried to put my prop/string value with ${}

```
replace(prop("all chapter numbers"),"(?:[^,]*,){${total checked chapter}}","" )
```

but in this one it did not saw my value and counted as 0 so [the result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zOAXq.png)

if i try to change the "" double quotes like this

```
replace(prop("all chapter numbers"),`(?:[^,]*,){${total checked chapter}}`,"" )
```

it will give me the same syntax issue on the other examples [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jCtSC.png)

i even tried another solution i have seen that uses '\b{replacethis}\b'

```
replace(prop("all chapter numbers"),`\\b${total checked chapters}\\b` , "")
```

[results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iA4YN.png)
[regex results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KT327.png)

Comment: Use template literal. Then `${prop(......)}`

Comment: if i add the template with ${prop()} it still doesn't fix the issue and gives the same errors because of quotation marks.  

replaceAll(replace(prop("all chapter numbers"),"(?:[^,]*,){${prop("total checked chapter")}}", ""), ",.*", "")

Error! ==
) expected (char 89)

Comment: That's not a template literal. Please look up the documentation on that subject.

Comment: I have checked the documentations: "Template literals are literals delimited with backtick (`) characters, allowing for multi-line strings, ..." The issue is... in any part of this formula i can't use the backtick.... If i try to change it or add it it will always give me a Syntax error related to it.. On notions formulas for me to use replace like replaceAll(text, text, text) i have to use replace("text","text","text") syntax and i can't interchange any of them with this . I am pretty new on this so apologies if i didn't understand something correctly.

Comment: anywhere where you can use string literals you can use template literals. They are just syntax for string literals with interpolation possibilities.

Comment: I understand that... But the issue still persists if i use a template literal instead of string literal it will just print out an error saying. " excepted . and not even on the part i used a regex. It will give me the same issue and error output on any place where i try to use it.

Comment: I don't know which code you are talking about as there are no template literals in your question.

Comment: I updated the question and tried to show as much trial and erorr with the thought process behind it . could you please check what am i not doing right or not seeing it clearly @trincot

Comment: Can you edit your question and include (as typed text, not as image) sample input/output? Like: what is the value of `prop("total checked chapter")` and of `prop("all chapter numbers")` and what you expect as result after having called the `replace` function for these values?